# Hibernate stopped do auto-flushing after changing ID Long type to UUID

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Hibernate 6.1.6.Final. My first example works fine:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
class MyEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null
)

@Entity(name = "my_entity_access")
@Immutable
class MyEntityAccessView(
/** some fields here **/
)
```

Then I changed ID type to UUID:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
class MyEntity(
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    var id: UUID? = null
)
```

And now I have a problem with this test below (I get null here):

```kotlin
@Test
fun example() {
    val savedEntity: MyEntity = myEntityRepository.save(MyEntity())
    val access: MyEntityAccessView = accessRepository.save(
        generateMyEntityAccessView(savedEntity)
    )
    
    assertNotNull(access) // OK
    val myEntityWithAccess: MyEntityView = viewRepository.findById(savedEntity.id!!)

    assertNotNull(myEntityWithAccess) // Failed
}
```

When I change `viewRepository.save(generateMyEntityAccessView())` to `viewRepository.saveAndFlush(generateMyEntityAccessView())` it works correctly.

Why did it happen and is there any way to avoid *saveAndFlush*? I changed id type only, nothing else.

Comment: I can't pinpoint the issue, but it is most likely related to the first level cache / persistent context of JPA. I recently made a talk about this https://www.vmware.com/explore/video-library/video-landing.html?sessionid=1678447579988001SjFx&videoId=6335272164112